# Git cannot parse "reword" command on interactive rebase

Tags: git, rebase

I am trying to reword a commit message of a very old commit. However, Git is complaining about my syntax for interactive rebase even though I typed the correct syntax as shown:

```
r e9e5e3b5e9d4 DEV-279360: Modified confirm page
pick c55f45961bc0 DEV-281040: No longer referencing the IpSecurity XML config for VMC. Cleaned up the VmcIpSecurityFilter logic. Created the Rest Api Security Filter
pick a46f88309112 DEV-281040: Auto-denying VMC REST API entry unless in the environment-specific XML. Switching it exact matcher.
```

The resulting error:

```
pick 67b6cf9ec8a8 DEV-277597: add 'Data Replication' to vault_package_type_v picklist.
pick 2c5a2ed8e4e8 DEV-284073: set cloning rule to true for integration and integration point
pick
error: invalid line 1: r e9e5e3b5e9d4 DEV-279360: Modified confirm page
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please provide text, not images when possible. You might also find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) interesting to re-write your question.

Comment: What version of Git are you using?

Comment: [please do not post images of text](https://benknoble.github.io/blog/2019/11/24/pics-text/)

Comment: @bk2204. git --version returns:   git version 2.23.0.windows.1